# What do I do if a object (from a class with default values) is instantiated with invalid values

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I have a program for my CSC class that prints out shapes made out of asterisks. I basically have everything down pact besides the fact that shapes cannot be made from invalid widths and heights (less than 0). The default values are W = 1 and H = 1, and I have a range check to ignore the value if it isn't above 0. My problem is that when you instantiate a shape with a number equal to or less than 0, it doesn't set it to the default values after it finds out that the number isn't valid.

Here's a simpler program I made that addresses my problem dealing with numbers.

```
# A simple class to create numbers that are higher than 0
class Num(object):
    def __init__(self, number = 1):
        self.number = number

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._number

    @number.setter
    def number(self, number):
        if number >= 1:
            self._number = number

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.number)

#Default values are 1
n1 = Num()
print ("n1 is {}".format(n1))
#Instantiated with a number of 3, a positve value
n2 = Num(3)
print ("n2 is {}".format(n2))
#Tries to change number to a negative value, which is ignored
n2.number = -2
print ("n2 is {}".format(n2))
#0 is an invalid number, so it should be ignored and set back to the default value, 1, right?
n3 = Num(0)
print ("n3 is {}".format(n3))
```

n3 is supposed to have a value of 1; however, the value is 0

Comment: You are passing `0` in `number` while creating object. Number setter checks is the input value is `>=1` and since the value is `0` it will ignore and not change the value of `_number`.  Its the same as `n2.number = -2` use case. Since `_number` is a numeric variable its default value is `0`. That's why you are getting zero back. You should have a else block in `number` setter to assign `1` to `_number`. But that will fail `n2.number = -2` use case.

Comment: I get that.  Do you know how to fix it though xD?

Comment: You want two different behaviors between constructor and number setter. You want to ignore the invalid value in number setter and you want to use 1 as default in constructor if the value is invalid. You can set `self._number =1` in constructor before `self.number = number`. This will serve both of your purposes

Comment: Oh my gosh, bro.  I never would've thought of that.  Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Edit2:
added a correct condition to setter and now it works as expected:

```
# A simple class to create numbers that are higher than 0
class Num(object):
    def __init__(self, number = 1):
        self.number = number  # this will call the setter method

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._number  # internal attribute which holding our actual value

    @number.setter
    def number(self, number):
        if number >= 1:
            # define our internal variable, can be any name
            self._number = number
        else:
            self._number = 1

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.number)

#Default values are 1
n1 = Num()
print ("n1 is {}".format(n1))
#Instantiated with a number of 3, a positve value
n2 = Num(3)
print ("n2 is {}".format(n2))
#Tries to change number to a negative value, which is ignored
n2.number = -2
print ("n2 is {}".format(n2))
#0 is an invalid number, so it should be ignored and set back to the default value, 1, right?
n3 = Num(0)
print ("n3 is {}".format(n3))
```

output:

```
n1 is 1  # n1 = Num()
n2 is 3  # n2 = Num(3)
n2 is 1  # n2.number = -2
n3 is 1  # n3 = Num(0)
```

Comment: ok, I realized that, but the problem of the 0 not being changed to 1 since it's an invalid value still persists.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a typo; it's perfectly reasonable to use the setter to initialize the property.

Comment: @Thebirdcried check my edited answer now it works as expected